# Changing the text size is not working

Tags: fontsize, document-classes

I am an eighth grader that needs some help.  I am a noob at anything TeX or LaTeX, and am just starting out.  I am using USBTeX, just in case that matters.

I cannot seem to change the text size in the `\documentclass[]{}` thingy in the beginning of the document.  My TeX editor sets it to `10pt` at default, but when I try to change it to something different, nothing happens.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `\documentclass[11pt]{...}` or `\documentclass[12pt]{...}`? There are only certain sizes supported by certain document classes. What document class are you using? Also, what size do you want it to change to? Do you receive any errors/warnings when you compile? If so, what do they say?

Comment: Alright, so I am using article, this is what my "mentor" told me to use.  And I think the error is something like "font size not used" or something similar...

Comment: A big welcome to TeX.SX! If you want a better range of font size options, with things like `\Large` suitably adjusted, you might want to try `memoir`. Something like `\documentclass[9pt,article]{memoir}`. It has lots more, too, and might be a good path for investing your learning time.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The only sizes supported by the document class option in the standard classes are 10pt 11pt and 12pt. To get text at other sizes you can use commands such as `\large` or `\tiny` within the document. Normally though you should not be using font size commands within a document. Heading commands such as `\section` and other structural markup should be defined by the class to use an appropriate size. One of the aims of LaTeX is that you should as far as possible be using structural markup such as `\section` and `\subsection` and not using explicit font and size changes, which make it a lot harder to reformat your document for different purposes.

Answer (score 14):

You may already have a document class with the `ext` prefix on it (such as `extarticle` instead of `article` as the document class.  Give it a try, it works for the [font sizes](http://vesta.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/extsizes/extsizes.pdf) 8pt, 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt, and 20pt.

These document classes are available from the [extsizes](https://ctan.org/pkg/extsizes) package, included in the Ubuntu package [texlive-latex-recommended](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/texlive-latex-recommended).